# Styling option element hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to style an option element hover state. By default it's blue, but I need it to be green. Is it possible to style the element? I'm using bootstrap V3. I know how to change the color of the option by adding a class, but how to change the hover state color? It's always blue - no matter what are you doing.
Please tell me if it's even possible. If it's not I'm going to figure something out.

ps. Uniforms are fine too as long as they work with bootstrap V3

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is an "option element" in this case? Code, please.

Comment: Drop-down menus are usually implemented using operating system controls, so they're out of control of CSS. If you want detailed control, use a plugin like Select2.

Comment: Are you using a plugin? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Code is really simple:

<select>
<option>Option name</option>
</select>

That option element i want to style. ps. No plugin is used and I'm asking for help :)

sorry.. i don't know how to use stackoverflow correctly..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you cant reliably theme built in select dropdown elements.
However there are scripts out there that make it possible to theme select lists.

```
//i found an example on google, its not mine so i wont copy it here. but link is below.
```

[Code i found on google](http://jsfiddle.net/bluetidepro/vWLEn/)

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer, using bootstrap instead.
[Js Fiddle using Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/ZuMv5/5/)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, 
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background : #AAAFDA !important;
    font-weight : bold;
    border-radius : 22px;
    color: lightBlue;
}

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li id="special"><a href="#">Dropdown link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not a good option. I have ~10 select's in each form. There is more than 50 forms :)

Comment: All 50 forms with 10 elements on one page ?

So the problem is that its slow ?

Comment: All 50 forms with atleast 10 select's on page :) And the problem is not that this is slow, but with this i will have to rewrite all off the select form elements :)

Comment: 50 hard coded forms....makes me think you dont have the best design going on there :)

have you tried to generate those forms dynamically?

can you post a link to the site

Comment: It's not hardcoded :) And yes it's a mess there, but boss said to do it and i'm doing it :)

And sorry - can't post the link..

Comment: Well, thats pretty much "take it or leave it" as other users mentioned , you cant theme built in options reliably. 

Replacing them with bootstrap options shouldnt be that difficult nor require that much time.

Its more or less copy paste. 
select tag = button tag
and option tag = li tag

Comment: Well yeah, you are kinda right, but i know that there is an Uniform, which could do that with javascript :) To tell the truth i just wanted to know if someone has ir or seen it for bootstrap v3